# queueOutputData error: The data argument must contain one column for each output channel in the session

Tags: session, view, matlab

Not entirely sure why I keep getting this error from `queueOutputData`:

> The data argument must contain one column for each output channel in the session.

I only have one output channel why would I need anymore columns? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
%Initial variables

%set stimulation protoccol
t = 0:1/fs:stimlength;
data = sawtooth(2*pi*freq*t,0.5);
data=data+1;
data=data*ampli;


%set video object, set frames per trigger

vid = videoinput('dalsa', 1, 'C:\Users\IOS User\Documents\MATLAB\IOS\D_DS-21-       01M60_12b_SC.cca');
set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',FRAMERATE*length);

%Set stim callback halfway through acquisiton
set(vid,'FramesAcquiredFcnCount', FRAMERATE*length/2+1);
set(vid,'FramesAcquiredFcn', {'stimulate'});


%Create session object and save it to the variable, ao
ao = daq.createSession('ni');

ao.Rate = 10000;

%Add an analog output 'Voltage' channel:
ao.addAnalogOutputChannel('Dev1',0,'Voltage')

ao.queueOutputData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is a row vector, meaning it has many columns.  Just do:

```
ao.queueOutputData(data.');
```